# Cannot swipe to switch UICollectionView page if you begin gesture on a cell

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, uicontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains a single `UIButton` in each cell. I've discovered it's difficult to swipe between the horizontal pages because if you touch down on a cell to begin the swipe, the `UIButton` touch events are triggered instead of allowing the swipe gesture to occur. I do have Delays Content Touches enabled for the collection view. What can I do to solve this so that it will recognize the page pan swipe gesture when you begin swiping on a cell? Perhaps the amount of delay can be increased before it recognizes a `UIControl` event?

Note that I do need to preserve the touch events for the buttons - I need to know when these events occur: TouchDown, TouchDragEnter, TouchCancel, TouchDragExit, and TouchUpInside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was only a problem in iOS 8.0 (at least the simulator), as I'm no longer experiencing it in iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Without the knowledge of whether you add the gesture recognizer in storyboard or by code, I can only suggest that you can try to creates a dependency relationship between the cell's gesture recognizer and the other gesture recognizer.

```
- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Comment: I don't have any gesture recognizers applied to the cells.

Comment: @Joey Then It is the button in the cell that somehow prevent you from scrolling. I tried this: 1.scroll direction = horizontal 2.scrolling enabled = yes 3. paging enabled = yes 4. direction lock enabled = yes. It works fine

Comment: Indeed it is a problem with the button in the cells. How can I allow it to page but still allow interacting with the button - call methods on touch events like TouchDown and TouchUpInside?

Comment: @Joey This might not help you solve the problem directly but I think whatever you want to do with the button you can do it in `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I don't believe so unfortunately. I need to handle TouchDown, TouchDragEnter, TouchCancel, TouchDragExit, and TouchUpInside - only knowing when they select a cell won't be sufficient.

Comment: @Joey In my opinion you can't drag the background scrollView because your button has already caught the drag related gesture. What I indicated in my last comment is it's time for you to think about whether this is a 'how to implement' problem or a design problem

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I need to find a solution regardless of what you'd categorize the problem as. :p `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` won't do the trick because it's not gesture recognizers that's the problem, it's the `UIControl` events being triggered instead of the scroll gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `delaysContentTouches` to `YES` on your `UICollectionView`. That way, there will be a small delay before the cells will receive a touch, and the built-in swipe recogniser can do its work.
You can also do that from the nib/storyboard by ticking the appropriate checkmark in IB:

[image: delay content touches checkmark]